# How does Passive EC2 instance work in case of active-passive failover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-passive

I want to configure active-passive failover with Route-53 in which primary (Active) resource is available/running and in case of any failure, Passive instance should take over.

I want to know how we need to configure Passive EC2 instance.

I am referring to the article [Active-active and active-passive failover - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-types.html#dns-failover-types-active-passive-one-resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given scenario, if Amazon Route 53 detects a failure, it simply sends the traffic to the alternate instance.

That instance should already be fully configured ready to process any traffic it receives.

It should use the same instance configuration as 'Active-Active', except it doesn't get any traffic when the primary instance is operating correctly.

Comment: Thanks John, so the only difference b/w Active-Active and Active-Passive is that in Active-Passive, Passive don't receive any traffic till Active instance is fully functional. Is there any way i can save the cost of Passive instance (Like make Passive instance stop and start only when my Active instance is not handling any traffic). Actually i don't to pay for Passive instance as i am not using it.

Comment: There is no "out-of-the-box" solution to auto-start the other instance, but as @Amandeep points out, it could be automated by a CloudWatch alarm and an AWS Lambda function. Or, run 2 x half-size instances as Active-Active all the time for the same total price.

Answer (score 0):

[image: AWS_CLOUDWATCH_EVENT_SCREENSHOT]just to add to the above comment from John, You can use cloud watch to monitor the heart beat and spin up the passive instance aka make it active when you need it.

Yes, you can add a cron job or event. I am not sure whether you can use a combination of both. Refer to the screenshot for details.
In the screenshot i assumed that you have aaaaaaa as your prod instance and bbbbbbbbb as your DR instance.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. While good for saving money, it would mean result in a system outage for several minutes while CloudWatch reacts to the outage and EC2 starts the instance. So it's a trade-off between cost and performance. That's why many people prefer an Active-Active system where both (all?) instances are always being used, and if something fails there is no outage (but it might be necessary to launch additional instances to handle the load).

Comment: @Amandeep ,Thanks for the answer. Is time dependent monitoring is possible through cloudwatch like only monitor from 9AM to 6PM ?

Comment: i wanted to add a screenshot therefore updated the main answer as i could not add in here. please refer above